# how to draw inverted round corners on selected list item?

Tags: html, css, border, css-shapes

Lets assume a set of boxes one below the other separated by some border.

If I set one of the boxes, it should have top-left-border-radius and bottom-left-border-radius

Also for the above box, bottom right border radius should be there without disturbing the flow of border and also the box below the selected one should have top right border radius without disturbing the flow of the border.

Image provided.

[image]

Comment: So what is the question? Also I don't understand your 3rd paragraph. So trying to guess what you're after, you can create different CSS classes: one for the one with no bottom-right-border radius and one with bottom-right-border radius. Same with the top-left-* ones.

Answer (score 2):

try this https://plnkr.co/edit/dN4LqEQGIG6hmegl7DRV?p=preview

```
                .box:nth-child(even){
              border: 1px solid #000;
              border-top-left-radius: 6px;
              border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
              border-right:none;
              border-top:none;
              border-bottom:none;
            }

            .box:nth-child(odd){
              border: 1px solid #000;
              border-top-right-radius: 6px;
              border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
              border-left:none;
              margin-left:4px;
            }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is not what OP is looking for. He wants to style active state. And this active state can be applied on any element. He don't need a hard code solution.

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
}
.first {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.second {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  width: 92px;
  margin-left: 8px;
}
.third {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  width: 92px;
}
.fourth {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="third"></div>
<div class="fourth"></div>
```

Comment: OP don't need a hard code solution. This active element can be any one from the available list items.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman What the OP needed is the figure in the image, thats why the image was provided. Obviously the code can be made more generic if the requirement arises.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure css way to achieve this.

Following `HTML` structure will be needed for this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>1</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>2</span>
  </li>
  .....
  .....
  .....
  <li>
    <span>n</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In this trick we will use `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements to draw round borders.

**Output Image:**

[image: Output Image]

> **Note:** This method will work if height of list items is fixed and same.

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(lightgreen, green);
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 20px 1%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li {
  position: relative;
}
ul li:before,
ul .active:after {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 100%;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
}
ul .active:before {
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
}
ul .active:after {
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  border-width: 2px 2px 0 0;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  margin-top: -2px;
  bottom: auto;
  top: 100%;
}
ul li:last-child.active:after {
  border-radius: 0;
}
ul .active + li:before {
  display: none;
}
ul .active + li + li:before {
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
}
ul li span {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  z-index: 5;
}
ul li:first-child span {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
}
ul li:first-child.active span {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}
ul li:last-child span {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
}
ul li:last-child.active span {
  border-width: 0;
}
ul .active + li:last-child span {
  border-right-width: 0;
}
ul .active span:before {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 2px 0 2px 2px;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  top: -2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="active"><span>1</span></li>
  <li><span>2</span></li>
  <li><span>3</span></li>
  <li><span>4</span></li>
  <li><span>5</span></li>
  <li><span>6</span></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><span>1</span></li>
  <li class="active"><span>2</span></li>
  <li><span>3</span></li>
  <li><span>4</span></li>
  <li><span>5</span></li>
  <li><span>6</span></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><span>1</span></li>
  <li><span>2</span></li>
  <li class="active"><span>3</span></li>
  <li><span>4</span></li>
  <li><span>5</span></li>
  <li><span>6</span></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><span>1</span></li>
  <li><span>2</span></li>
  <li><span>3</span></li>
  <li class="active"><span>4</span></li>
  <li><span>5</span></li>
  <li><span>6</span></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><span>1</span></li>
  <li><span>2</span></li>
  <li><span>3</span></li>
  <li><span>4</span></li>
  <li class="active"><span>5</span></li>
  <li><span>6</span></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><span>1</span></li>
  <li><span>2</span></li>
  <li><span>3</span></li>
  <li><span>4</span></li>
  <li><span>5</span></li>
  <li class="active"><span>6</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: **To the Downvoter:** Kindle leave a comment describing a reason for your downvote.

Comment: Nobody give you downvote , because this edges also good , up vote for that

Comment: @Naila Thank you, but somebody downvoted my answer. You have enough reputation to see vote counts. If you will click on vote counts you will see that.

Comment: @Naila Just click on vote counts on any question or answer. For example in my case click on `1` and you will see.

Answer (score 1):

from a list and a single pseudo, there is something to do too :

*(`tabindex` is added for the demo, you can click or tab through item to see borders and backgrounds switching)*,

*item's height and padding do not matter much but you need to mind the radius value and borders thickness , if necessary, to update margin  and or coordonates to match the value used*

```css
ul {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, white, #0F4782, #069ED5, white);
  border-bottom: solid;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 1em;
}
li {
  display: block;
  border: solid;
  border-left: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
li:focus,
li:active {
  outline: none;
  border: solid;
  border-right: none;
  position: relative;
  left: -.5em;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: -3px;
  border-radius: 0.5em 0 0 0.5em;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, tomato, white)
}
li:focus + li,
li:active + li {
  border-radius: 0 0.75em;
}
li:focus:before,
li:active:before {
  content: '';
  border-radius: 0.75em;
  border: solid transparent;
  border-bottom: solid;
  position: absolute;
  right: -8px;
  bottom: 100%;
  height: 0.75em;
  width: 0.75em;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  ;
}
li:focus i, li:active i {display:none;}
li:focus:after,
li:active:after {
  content: '> focused';
  font-weight:bold;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li tabindex="0">item <i>click me</i></li>
  <li tabindex="0">item<br/>  <i>click me</i></li>
  <li tabindex="0">item <i>click me</i></li>
  <li tabindex="0">item <i>click me</i></li>
  <li tabindex="0">item <i>click me</i></li>
  <li tabindex="0">item <i>click me</i></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice +1 . A minor point. `border-radius` of first item needs to adjusted a bit while it is active.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.box{
  width:300px;
  height:30px;
  border:2px solid #000;
  display:block;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin-left:10px;
  }
#one,#two,#four{
  
  border-left:none;
  
  }
#two{
  border-bottom-right-radius:20px;
  }
#one,#three{
  border-bottom:none;
  }
#three{
  border-top:none;
  border-right:none;
  border-bottom-left-radius:20px;
  border-top-left-radius:20px;
  margin-left:0px;
  width:40px;
  }
#four{
  border-top-right-radius:20px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="one" class="box"></div>
<div id="two" class="box"></div>
<div id="three" class="box"></div>
<div id="four" class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  padding:20px;
}
li:nth-child(1) {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  margin-left: 13px;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  border-left: 1px solid;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  margin-right: 13px;
}
li:nth-child(4) {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dear please check with this snippet , i just give you the perfect shape. This is exactly what you need check with the edges

```css
.box1 {
 width:300px;
 height:100px;
 border:1px solid #000;
 border-left:0;
 border-right-width:2px;
}
.box2 {
 width:300px;
 height:100px;
 border-right:2px solid #000;
 border-bottom-right-radius:20px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
 position:relative;
}
.box2::after {
 position:absolute;
 right:-2px;
 width:30px;
 height:30px;
 border-bottom:2px solid #000;
 border-right:2px solid #000;
 border-bottom-right-radius:20px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
 bottom:0px;
 content:"";
}
.box2::before {
 position:absolute;
 right:16px;
 width:90%;
 height:2px;
 background:#000;
 bottom:0px;
 content:"";
}
.box3 {
 width:281px;
 height:100px;
 border-bottom:2px solid #000;
 border-left:2px solid #000;
 border-top-left-radius:20px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:20px;
 position:relative;
}
.box3::after {
 position:absolute;
 left:-2px;
 width:30px;
 height:30px;
 border-top:2px solid #000;
 border-left:2px solid #000;
 border-top-left-radius:20px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
 top:-2px;
 content:"";
}
.box4 {
 width:300px;
 height:100px;
 border-bottom:1px solid #000;
 border-right:2px solid #000;
 border-top-left-radius:20px;
 border-top-right-radius:20px;
 position:relative;
}
.box4::after {
 position:absolute;
 right:-2px;
 width:30px;
 height:30px;
 border-top:2px solid #000;
 border-right:2px solid #000;
 border-top-right-radius:20px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
 top:-2px;
 content:"";
}
```

```html
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
<div class="box3"></div>
<div class="box4"></div>
```

Comment: Dear @user2349115 please check the answer , may be this is exactly what you are looking for, if this answer is use full , don't forgot to tick the answer